# Xamarin.Form Android Notification Build Action Windows

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification

I have followed some step on how to create notification on a easier way.

In the video the press "Build Action"

They do this on a Mac and seams to be an action to connect an `*.json` file.

I cant find this action and I use Visual Studio Xamarin.Form Cross platform on Windows

https://youtu.be/TT11e_YCRwI?t=498

[image]

Comment: You are not able to find build action option or inside _build action_ not getting your proffered option?

Comment: @CGPA6.4 I have updated the Questian with picture now, so you can see that i cant se it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few options are little bit different in *Visual Studio Mac* than *Visual Studio*. In Windows to get *Build Action* of file you need to click Properties(As you doing already) than you will find option *Build Action* in Properties window.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, found that 30 min ago =D